# PHP alter and save cookie with starting value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, youtube

I've been trying out working with cookies *for the first time*, with some mixed results. I want the visitor to be able to choose if the youtube videos autoplay or not by altering 1 and 0 in the embed url, and their choice saved in a cookie for when they return. On first visit the video should autoplay. I think my problem might be not knowing how to set the new value to the cookie properly?

At the moment I'm struggling with preserving the value when the visitor views the page after and/or setting the value in the first place at all. The site works almost as expected as long as `?autoplay=0` is kept in the URL to prevent autoplay.

I'd need to save the last chosen state of autoplay in a cookie, so thatthe visitor doesn't need to re-select it every time upon returning.

Ideal (but not neccessary) solution would be to not need the `?autoplay=0` except for maybe when the visitor clicks the link to make the switch (don't know if this is easy or complicated to achive – but in my mind the cookie could make the url variable useless?).

**Index.php**

```
<?php
// This might be very unneccessary,
// should probably look at the cookie and not the url?
// Can't figure out how though.
if($_GET['autoplay'] == "0"){ 
$autoplay = "0"; 
}else{ 
$autoplay = "1"; 
}

setcookie("autoplay",$autoplay, time()+3600*24);
$_COOKIE['autoplay'] = $autoplay;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
        <button class="randomizerButton" data-href="data.php">Randomize</button>
        <hr>
        <div id="results">
        <?php include('data.php'); ?>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('button.randomizerButton').click(function(){
                    scriptUrl = $(this).attr('data-href');
                    $.post(scriptUrl, function(response){
                        $('#results').html(response);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php
$var = array(  
    array("Hello", "0wLljngvrpw", "10", "15"),   
    array("Hey", "TINASKjjNfw", "20", "25"),  
    array("Right in the dick! I shot you friend right in the di... Potatoes, Potatoes.", "rzU_fLcxIN0", "30", "35"),
);  
// array_rand returns the INDEX to the randomly 
// chosen value, use that to access the array. 
$finalVar = $var[array_rand($var)];  


echo('<iframe id="ytplayer" width="557" height="315" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'.$finalVar[1].'&start='.$finalVar[2].'&end='.$finalVar[3].'&autoplay='.$_COOKIE["autoplay"].'" 
frameborder="0"></iframe>');

?>
<a href="?autoplay=1">Autoplay 1</a>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="?autoplay=0">Autoplay 0</a>
<br><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to set the cookie only when the url parameter is there ( when one of the linked have been clicked ). Just check if the parameter is set  :

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['autoplay']) || !isset($_COOKIE['autoplay'])) {
    if($_GET['autoplay'] == "0"){ 
        $autoplay = "0"; 
    } 
    else{ 
        $autoplay = "1"; 
    }

    setcookie("autoplay",$autoplay, time()+3600*24);
    $_COOKIE['autoplay'] = $autoplay;
}

?>
```

The `|| ! isset ($_COOKIE['autoplay'])`   is because you wanted  1 as the default value if the user never choosed any yet. it means " if the cookie value doesn't exist "